# What is sync git keyboard shortcut in visual studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to use keyboard shortcut to sync git repository.

What is sync git keyboard shortcut in visual studio?

[image: Team Explorer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following shortcut will help to push, pull, fetch. (Though this is not for sync)

`ctrl` + `alt` + `F3` will open the git branches menu from the status bar.

Then press `L` (Pull), `F` (Fetch), `P` (Push) accordingly.

[image: gitimage]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Ctrl+0, Ctrl+Y to go to the Synchronization panel in Team Explorer.
While on Synchronization, you can click on Sync (or Push or Pull).
Use Ctrl+0, Ctrl+G to go back to the Changes pane.

That isn't a single shortcut, but it can help.
See the full list of shortcuts here: http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2017/

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there's a shortcut for this. However, according to [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pulling?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio#update-branches-with-merge):

> Sync is a combined operation of pulling remote changes and then pushing local ones, synchronizing the commits on the local and remote branch.

Thus, you can reproduce the same behavior with a couple of git commands, for example:

```
git pull --rebase mybranch origin/mybranch
git push origin mybranch
```

The actual commands might be different depending on how exactly you'd like to sync.